# Is there a way to increment JSON array key value through multiple arrays instead of starting over with each array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is my first time using JSON so I'm not even sure if I'm asking this question correctly but hopefully you can understand what I'm getting at.

I am using the following data that to populate a select option based on the selection made in the previous select:

```
        prods = {
        Cookware: ["- Select -", "Round French Oven", "Oval French Oven", "Braiser", "Skillet", "Fry Pan", "Grill Pan", "Saute Pan", "Saucepan", "Saucier", "Griddle", "Roaster", "Stockpot", "Speciality Cookware", "Other"],
        Bakeware: ["- Select -", "Covered Casserole", "Baking Dish", "Stoneware Gratin", "Speciality Bakeware", "Individual Bakeware", "Metal Bakeware", "Other"],
        KitchenTools: ["- Select -", "Utensils", "Kitchen Accessories", "Cutlery", "Wine Tools", "Textiles", "Other"],
        DineEntertain: ["- Select -", "Dinnerware", "Serveware", "Tabletop Accessories", "Glassware", "Kettles", "Tea Collection", "Café Collection", "Other"]
        };
```

and here is the relevant jQuery I am using to do this:

```
                $.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                    nextProdType
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", key)
                        .attr("name", value)
                        .text(value));
                });
```

In the resulting HTML, the key counter starts over for each array. So if Bakeware is selected:

```
            <option value="0" name="- Select -">- Select -</option>
            <option value="1" name="Covered Casserole">Covered Casserole</option>
            <option value="2" name="Baking Dish">Baking Dish</option>
            <option value="3" name="Stoneware Gratin">Stoneware Gratin</option>
```

or if Accessories is selected:

```
        <option value="0" name="- Select -">- Select -</option>
        <option value="1" name="Utensils">Utensils</option>
        <option value="2" name="Kitchen Accessories">Kitchen Accessories</option>
        <option value="3" name="Cutlery">Cutlery</option>
```

As you can see the value always starts at 0, and what I would like is for the first `- select -` value to be 0 and the last option in DineEntertain be 39.  This would allow me to store all these options in one table in the database without having duplicate numerical values.

I am using this on a dynamic form where users can add or subtract categories, so the value has to be fixed. 
Is there a way to do this?  I have tried searching for this in the forums here and in Google but not finding any solutions, which makes me think I may not be asking the right question...

Comment: Why do your `<option>` elements have a name attribute? :)

Comment: Good question! Because I copied this code from someone els and didn't bother to clean that up! I will remove that line from the jQuery, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redefine your array, you'll get what you want.  I suggest, though, that you're not storing - Select - over and over in your database, right?

```
prods = {
    Cookware: {0:"- Select -", 1:"Round French Oven", 2:"Oval French Oven", 3:"Braiser", "Skillet", "Fry Pan", "Grill Pan", "Saute Pan", "Saucepan", "Saucier", "Griddle", "Roaster", "Stockpot", "Speciality Cookware", "Other"},
    Bakeware: {"- Select -", "Covered Casserole", "Baking Dish", "Stoneware Gratin", "Speciality Bakeware", "Individual Bakeware", "Metal Bakeware", "Other"},
    KitchenTools: {"- Select -", "Utensils", "Kitchen Accessories", "Cutlery", "Wine Tools", "Textiles", "Other"},
    DineEntertain: {0:"- Select -", "Dinnerware", "Serveware", "Tabletop Accessories", "Glassware", "Kettles", "Tea Collection", "Café Collection", 39:"Other"}
    };
```

Now, I was lazy there, **so be sure to fill in all the other `##:""` numbers!**  But, as you can see from the first row, the numbers get assigned; and, from the last row, you can set all the `- Select -` to 0.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, my page breaks when I try this.  It should be 0:"value", correct?

Comment: I didn't fill in every number.  Each item in the prods object needs to point to another object where all the key/value pairs are defined.

Comment: Weird, it still doesn't work. I have assigned a value to each item. I tried setting each select to 0 and then only the first and last (wasn't sure based on your example). There are no error messages in the console. This is the page if you want to look at it: http://lcoawebservices.com/prod-reg-v2.html.  Clicking Register Product should reveal the form I'm working on.

Comment: Ah, you didn't change the `[]` to `{}`.  Notice the 3rd character after "KitchenTools", for example... I changed them to objects instead of arrays.  Does that help? EDIT: And don't forget the closing bracket!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value in the loop.

```
$.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                nextProdType
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", key) <-- Here
                    .attr("name", value)
                    .text(value));
            });
```

Use your own logic and populate it there.

Some thing like below,

```
var counter = 0; // In global scope.

$.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                nextProdType
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", counter++)
                    .attr("name", value)
                    .text(value));
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! I see what you're saying but unfortunately that won't work.  There are dynamic form fields being added or subtracted here and this approach increments with each one, rather than assigning a fixed value to each option.  I will update my question.

Comment: The best place to do that should be server side. You should be sending the value/id in the json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all those values in the same table, without having to work with id numbers.
I would suggest you would use a table structure like :

id, category, value

1, Cookware, Round French Oven
etc

And when selecting, you can just select by the value in category.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global counter variable initializing it to 0
just increment for each loop and replace .attr("value", key) with .attr("value", counter++)